# R: Apply function to only "factor" variables

Tags: r, dataframe, function, data-manipulation

I am working with R.  I have a dataset with both character and numeric variables - I am trying to replace all NA's and empty values in this data with "0".

Recently, I learned how to replace "NA" values within factor variables as 0 ([R: replacing <NA> within factor variables as 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68752786/r-replacing-na-within-factor-variables-as-0)):

```
# "df" is the dataset, "a" is the variable
#Include 0 in the levels for "a" variable
levels(df$a) <- c(levels(df$a), 0)
#Replace NA to 0
df[is.na(df)] <- 0
```

Now, I am trying to learn how to apply this command on every factor variable within "df".

I learned how to identify all columns that contain "factor" variables:

```
is.fact <- sapply(df, is.factor)
```

From here, is there a way to run this command

```
levels(df$a) <- c(levels(df$a), 0)
```

for every factor variable in the data?

Currently, I was planning on manually rewriting this command for all the variables, e.g.:

```
levels(df$a) <- c(levels(df$a), 0)
levels(df$b) <- c(levels(df$b), 0)
levels(df$c) <- c(levels(df$c), 0)
```

etc

And then run the following line:

```
df[is.na(df)] <- 0
```

But I was trying to find a quicker way to do this.

Does anyone know how to do this? Can someone please show me a quicker way to solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could use `dplyr` and `tidyr` for this task:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  tibble() %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.factor), ~replace_na(`levels<-`(.x, c(levels(.x), 0)), 0)))
```

The main idea is using `dplyr`'s `across` function to find every column with `factors` and applying your function on this. The second idea used here is  the fact that

```r
levels(df$a) <- c(levels(df$a), 0)
```

is the same as

```r
`levels<-`(df$a, c(levels(df$a), 0))
```

The assignment is just a special kind of function we can use inside a pipe. So the code applied to

```r
df <- structure(list(a = structure(c(9L, 16L, 3L, 19L, 8L, 15L, 8L, 
14L, 13L, NA, 13L, 6L, 2L, 11L, 1L, NA, 18L, 12L, 7L, 1L, 5L, 
6L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 12L, 10L, 5L, 4L, NA), .Label = c("b", "c", 
"d", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "t", 
"u", "v", "w", "y"), class = "factor"), b = structure(c(11L, 
4L, 5L, 9L, 12L, 7L, NA, NA, 13L, 9L, 1L, 8L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 12L, 
NA, 10L, NA, 13L, NA, 3L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 6L, NA, 5L, NA), .Label = c("a", 
"b", "d", "e", "h", "j", "k", "q", "s", "t", "x", "y", "z"), class = "factor"), 
    A = c("d", "b", "o", "t", "u", "m", "i", "e", "d", "t", "v", 
    "t", "g", "o", "b", "j", "h", "b", NA, "x", "g", "s", "j", 
    "b", "c", "i", "b", "b", "h", "i")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-30L))
```

returns

```r
# A tibble: 30 x 3
   a     b     A    
   <fct> <fct> <chr>
 1 k     x     d    
 2 u     e     b    
 3 d     h     o    
 4 y     s     t    
 5 j     y     u    
 6 t     k     m    
 7 j     0     i    
 8 p     0     e    
 9 o     z     d    
10 0     s     t    
11 o     a     v    
12 h     q     t    
13 c     d     g    
14 m     b     o    
15 b     d     b    
16 0     y     j    
17 w     0     h    
18 n     t     b    
19 i     0     NA   
20 b     z     x    
21 g     0     g    
22 h     d     s    
23 v     a     j    
24 w     0     b    
25 y     0     c    
26 n     0     i    
27 l     j     b    
28 g     0     b    
29 f     h     h    
30 0     0     i
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R option (borrow `df` from [@Martin Gal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68753404/12158757))

```
list2DF(
  lapply(
    df,
    function(x) {
      if (is.factor(x)) {
        replace(`levels<-`(x, c(levels(x), 0)), is.na(x), 0)
      } else {
        x
      }
    }
  )
)
```

which gives

```
   a b    A
1  k x    d
2  u e    b
3  d h    o
4  y s    t
5  j y    u
6  t k    m
7  j 0    i
8  p 0    e
9  o z    d
10 0 s    t
11 o a    v
12 h q    t
13 c d    g
14 m b    o
15 b d    b
16 0 y    j
17 w 0    h
18 n t    b
19 i 0 <NA>
20 b z    x
21 g 0    g
22 h d    s
23 v a    j
24 w 0    b
25 y 0    c
26 n 0    i
27 l j    b
28 g 0    b
29 f h    h
30 0 0    i
```

Answer (score 2):

You can `lapply` once and do the work to every column.  During processing each column, you can check if the column is the `Factor` or not.  If it is factor vector do the conversion, if not just return the column as it is.

Here is the complete code with a sample `data.frame`.

```
df <- data.frame(
    a = factor(c(1, 2, 4, NA, 5, 6)),
    b = c("a", "b", "c", NA, "e", "f"),
    c = factor(c(NA, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
)

replaceNA <- function (df) {
    result <- lapply(df, function(col) {
        if (is.factor(col)) {
            levels(col) <- c(levels(col), 0)
        }
        return (col)
    })
    result[is.na(result)] <- 0
    return (result)
}

replaceNA(df)
```